# Flex converting numeric string to exponential form

Tags: xml, web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, soap

This is a weird issue I came across or a Flex 3 shortcoming. I am using SOAP messaging protocol and the response from the server for filling the 'Notes' field which I have on a pop-up looks like this:

[image: Fiddler response - GLNotes]

Since this is SOAP I am getting the response as a XML string. The GLNotes field value is 4582e12.

Some Flex code on how I handle this response:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{AccruedIncomeWS.GetAccruedIncomeList.lastResult.root.AccruedIncomeList.Item}" 
itemClick="AccrualClick(event);" id="AccrualList>
    <mx:columns>
        ...
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Now I created a watch expression for AccrualList.selectedItem and I see:

[image: SelectedItem numeric data]

Why is the GLNotes getting converted to a Number here? To test out this implicit conversion I put some characters in the notes field and got this in the watch expression:

[image: SelectedItem string data]

With the presence of some alphabets the GLNotes field is treated as a string. Is there anyway I can make this value strongly typed and not have any implicit conversions applied? Let me know if additional info is required. Thanks!

**Edit:**

As @Pan suggested, I changed my dataProvider to be an *ArrayCollection* AccrualDataProvider.

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{AccrualDataProvider}" itemClick="AccrualClick(event);" id="AccrualList>
    <mx:columns>
        ...
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Handling the response from the server and filling the *ArrayCollection* with it.

```
private function HandleAccrualList(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    AccrualDataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
    AccrualDataProvider = AppHelper.ForceArrayCollection(event.result.root.AccruedIncomeList.Item);
}
```

On Debug, I found that, the *ArrayCollection* AccrualDataProvider still contains GLNotes as a Number as opposed to a string.

[image: DataProvider object]

It's sad that we have to write some extra code to avoid this implicit conversion, what I do for a work-around is: preceed the GLNotes with a '/' when sending from the server and then in the labelFunction, unescape the '/'. So flex treats it as a string and keeps the numeric string unchanged.

Is there any setting that can be done on the server side, so the XML forces a datatype of string to the SOAP XML response?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#labelFunction) for show custom view with datagrid data.

Here is an example(the data provider is array not xml)

```
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        private var Item:Object = [{GLNodes:0x4582e12},{GLNodes:0x4582e13}];

        private function GLNodesLabelFunction(obj:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
        {
            return (obj.GLNodes).toString(16);//show exponential form
        }
    ]]>
 </mx:Script>

 <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{Item}" id="AccrualList">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="GLNodesLabelFunction"/>
    </mx:columns>
 </mx:DataGrid>
```

If the problem still existed after you use labelFunction, I think the problem may be how you use xml dataProvider.